# Can you "fulfill" on a beta site to which you didn't commit?

Tags: support, area-51

I know that when I'm on Area 51, if I've committed to a Beta site, it will change my "beta user" indicator to a "fulfilled" indicator when I've asked or answered enough questions (10, I think).

The question is this: If I don't commit to a beta proposal, but then participate in the public beta, (at which point I think  shows "beta user" on A51) will it then switch to "fulfilled" once I post enough questions and/or answers, or will it not, since I never made a commitment that could then be "fulfilled"?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that since you didn't make a commitment, you have nothing to fulfill, so it would keep saying "Beta users".

If it doesn't it's probably not intended.

Answer (score 0):

On area51 profiles, fulfillments are listed under **fulfilled commitments**.

Comment: that is a correct, but in this context useless statement

Comment: Adding "so, no" sounded patronising.